# Laravel upload - Any address must be copied and not?

Tags: laravel, upload

I have made a website at localhost and hosting. Sometimes I need to edit the code. Then upload to the hosting. You do not need to upload addresses where there are no changes. For example: vendor, maybe storage.
Do you need to copy addresses to address and not copy the address?

Comment: you question is very ambiguous. please explain more!

Comment: The Laravel core does not need uploade. The kernel does not change during programming. I do not know which directories are jardo.

Comment: Do you have vps or shared host?

Comment: I have shared host

Comment: Then if you have not access to shell (which is normal in shared hosts) then you cannot use git and you should upload all of the data in your project

Comment: Core Laravel did not change. Core Directory must uploaded? In which directories is the core?

Comment: every file you have changed should be uploaded. Includes vendor files. you should find the files that have been added by composer

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic laravel .gitignore which ommit vendor and storage.

```
    ### Laravel ###
vendor/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
```

The `vendor` folder is updated when you call `composer update / install`. Editing this files is a bad practice.

`Storage` use to be related to user data, system logs... which are daily usage data.

So you don't need them both on your code host since they aren't neccesary to deploy your app